# Sorting file paths in python 3.4

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.4

ok, so what i need to do is sort a list of file paths in python 3.4.
they need to be in alphabetical order but sub-folders and their contents are first

example output:

```
b/e/f.txt
b/d.txt
g/u.txt
i/a/q.txt
a.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

i have been trying to figure out how to do this for the last few hours with Google but no luck

i'm afraid i don't have access to a v2 interpreter at the moment so i can't verify the correctness of this, but in v2 it would look something like this:

```
def FileComp(File1, File2):
    if File1.count('/') == File2.count('/'):
        return File1 < File2;
    else
        Same = 0;
        FilePath1 = os.path.dirname(File1);
        FilePath2 = os.path.dirname(File2);
        FilePath1Len = len(FilePath1);
        FilePath2Len = len(FilePath2);
        while Same < FilePath1Len and Same < FilePath2Len and FilePath1[Same:Same] == FilePath2[Same:Same]:
            Same += 1;
        FilePath1 = FilePath1[Same:];
        FilePath2 = FilePath2[Same:];
        if len(FilePath1) == 0 or len(FilePath2) == 0:
            return len(FilePath1) > len(FilePath2);
        else
            return File1 < File2;

Files.sort(FileComp);
```

Comment: How about splitting them on `/` and then doing a sorting based on the least index?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to have subfolders sorted first, you need to provide two things to sort on: a flag if it is *not* a sub folder (`True` is sorted after `False`), and the path itself:

```
sorted(paths, key=lambda p: (os.path.sep not in p, p))
```

This uses `os.path.sep` to determine if a path is for a subfolder or not, so you get subfolders first.

So `'a.txt'` is transformed to `(True, 'a.txt')`, while `'b/d.txt'` is sorted as `(False, 'b/d.txt')`; tuples are sorted lexicographically with `False` sorted before `True`.

If you need *deeper* folders sorted before shallow folders, count the number of separators and return that as a *negative* value; the more slashes the 'deeper' the folder and it'll be sorted before others:

```
sorted(paths, key=lambda p: (-p.count(os.path.sep), p))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> paths = '''\
... b/e/f.txt
... b/d.txt
... a.txt
... c.txt
... '''.splitlines()
>>> sorted(paths, key=lambda p: (os.path.sep not in p, p))
['b/d.txt', 'b/e/f.txt', 'a.txt', 'c.txt']
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(paths)
>>> sorted(paths, key=lambda p: (os.path.sep not in p, p))
['b/d.txt', 'b/e/f.txt', 'a.txt', 'c.txt']
>>> sorted(paths, key=lambda p: (-p.count(os.path.sep), p))
['b/e/f.txt', 'b/d.txt', 'a.txt', 'c.txt']
```

Comment: i'm afraid i don't understand what you mean with the first part, but the output of me copy/pasted your code is completely random

Comment: @khm: it is not completely random; it is in sorted order with paths with a slash in them first, followed by paths without a slash. I added another option for you.

Comment: ok, i must have botched the copy/pasted some how because it stopped being random when i did it again, but the output still isn't right. i do appreciate the effort though.

Comment: The "negative value" approach won't work since `z/z.txt` will appear before `a/a/a.txt` due to the different number of path separators.

Comment: @ErikusMaximus: the negative value trick ensures that we sort the path count in reverse order while using forward sort for the path names. It sounds as if you want to reverse only the path name sort order, so don't negate the separator count.

Comment: I don't particularly care which direction you solution sorts, but consider how your algorithm will sort `a.txt`, `a/a/a.txt`, `b/b.txt`, `c/c/c/c/c/c/c.txt` and `z/z/z.txt`.  Your algorithm sorts first based on path length (number of inodes), and secondly on the actual dir/file names.  As such my file list earlier would be sorted as `c/c/c/c/c/c/c.txt`, `a/a/a.txt`, `z/z/z.txt`, `b/b.txt`, `a.txt`.

Comment: @ErikusMaximus: Yes, and that’s exactly the point. That’s what the question asked for. If you don’t want that, spit the paths on the path separator, and that’s your key.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, per the requester "they need to be in alphabetical order but sub-folders and their contents are first".  Your solution doesn't put them in alphabetical order.

Comment: @ErikusMaximus it puts the subfolders first and sorts them alphabetically within the two groups: those with and those without subfolders. That’s why `b/d.txt` is sorted before `b/e/f.txt`. The second solution makes more groups, one per subfolder depth, and within each group the folders are sorted alphabetically. This puts `b/e/f.txt` first as it has the higher folder count.

Comment: @ErikusMaximus note that the question includes the desired output; paths with subfolders first (and sorted as a group) followed by all paths without subfolders (again all sorted). Why do you think that my solution doesn’t put them in alphabetical order? Perhaps you expected subfolders starting with `a` to be grouped with files starting with `a`, then subfolders with `b`, together with files starting with `b`, etc.? That is not what the OP has asked for, their question is very specific, with a good example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the sort order depends on the number of subfolder levels in the path.

So the sorting has to use a key where this number of subfolder levels is taken into account. The easiest way is a `lambda` function which will give us a tuple of subfolder-level-count and the name of the path itself. The counter has to be negated, so that the paths with more subfolders will come first.

```
paths = ['a.txt', 'b/d.txt', 'b/e/f.txt', 'c.txt']
paths.sort(key=lambda x: (-x.count('/'), x))
```

Result

```
['b/e/f.txt', 'b/d.txt', 'a.txt', 'c.txt']
```

Comment: that's close, but doesn't quite get the actual list sorted correctly, i've updated the example to give a better idea of what is going on

Comment: That's a pretty strange sorting. If you can't describe the rules for this we can't find a computized solution.

Comment: how is it strange? it's in alphabetical order, but sub-folders come first

Comment: It looks like we have to do repeated grouping and sorting on every different level.

Comment: it was doable in python v2 with just a few lines of code. can v3 really not do it?

Comment: We might be able to adapt the Python 2 script. Please edit your question and add the code.

Comment: @Matthias: This was exactly what I was looking for: Sort by path-depth. My attempts resulted in > 5 lines, your oneliner is pretty neat and made my hour, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the game, but I had this problem myself and here is how I solved it.  My approach is to have the sort function split each path into a list of inodes (directories/files) so that individual directories and files are compared against each other instead of comparing entire paths.

```
paths = [
    'b/e/f.txt',
    'b/d.txt',
    'a.txt',
    'c.txt',
]

for path in sorted(paths.keys(), key=lambda s: s.lower().split(os.path.sep)):
    print(path)
```

I use `lower()` so my paths are sorted case-insensitively to avoid output like the following:

```
A.txt
B.txt
Z.txt
a.txt
b.txt
z.txt
```